# How to draw 2 datasets independently in a pyplot histogram ?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I'm trying to plot 2 datasets A and B in a histogram, but one of them contains way more values than the other, which makes the histogram difficult to read. Here are my code and the result:

```
plt.hist([A,B], 20, color=['yellowgreen', 'darkred'])
```

[image: cant read this histogram]

What I would like is that the scale (y-axis) does not depend on the absolute number of values, but on a percentage relative to the datasets. It would not change the red bars, but only the green ones, like this:

[image: this histogram is much better]

Any idea ? Thanks,

Telergoel

Comment: Use `normed=True` (be careful though since this takes the bin size into account). Or normalize it yourself, `hist_values *= 100 / histValues.sum()`

Comment: @Julien Why not provide this as an answer which can be accepted?

Comment: `normed=True` works fine, thanks ! I'd like to know if there is a way to display percentages on the y-axis as well, like in my example